# Variable is declared but still showing undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]I have a select list, and on change of it I need to set a  variable to true. I have written the code as shown below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var value = false;
console.log(value) //Get value = false
$("#select").on('change', function(){
    value = true;
    console.log(value) //Get value = true
});

$("#form").submit(function (e) {
     console.log(value) //Get value = undefined
})
})
```

Why do I get undefined after submitting the form. I want its value as true/false instead of undefined

Comment: please share html

Comment: you are missing  `});`  for  `$(document).ready(fumnction(){...all of your code...});`

Comment: Sorry. It was a typo, I have added it in my code

Comment: My HTML select list:
`<select id="select" name="gender">
      <option value="0">Select Gender</option>
      <option value="Male">Male</option>
      <option value="Female">Female</option>
     </select> `

Comment: @gauri where is the html for form

Comment: @gauri check my snippet..i have updated your form

Comment: HTML:

`<form class="form-horizontal" id="form" action="" method="POST">
<select id="select" name="gender"> <option value="0">Select Gender</option> <option value="Male">Male</option> <option value="Female">Female</option> </select> </form>`

Comment: @gauri your code is working properly, what is issue?
Here is jsbin link https://jsbin.com/wugesosuwa/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved..!! tried it the other way. Checked the value of select after submitting the form.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var value = false;
console.log(value) //Get value = false
$("#select").on('change', function(){
    value = true;
    console.log(value) //Get value = true
});
})
 $("#form").submit(function (e) {
     var select_value = $("#select").val();
     var value = false;
     if(select_value == "Female") {
         value = true;
     }
     console.log(value) //Get value = false/true
})
```

Comment: then there is no need to use `onchange` function

Comment: I have some `<div>` to show and hide on change of that value, so that will come in that block

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var value = false;
console.log(value) //Get value = false
$("#select").on('change', function(){
    value = true;
    console.log(value) //Get value = true
});

$("#form").submit(function (e) {
     console.log(value) //Get value = undefined
})
```

dont create a new variable inside your onchange function

Comment: Tried both ways to see if I could get something defined (true/false). But still get it undefined

Answer (score 1):

You are missing end brackets and also you can use the same global value in your onChange method

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var value = false; //Global default value
  console.log(value) //Get value = false
  $("#select").on('change', function() {
    value = true; //value changed on change
    console.log($('#select').val(), "value on change!")
    console.log(value) //Get value = true
  });

  $("#form").submit(function(e) {
    console.log(value) //it will be not undefined
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="javascript:alert( 'form success!' );">
  <select id="select" name="gender">
    <option value="0">Select Gender</option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: what additional I have to add in my code, because I checked with your code and I do not find any modification. Please guide me
P.S I have already added the cdn

Comment: maybe your existing variables are conflicting try to run my code in a fresh new file then check and compare it with your code. It might be variable confliction @gauri

Comment: @gauri can you attach screenshots of your output in the console?

Comment: I have added a SS of my console, please check. I couldn't add much, due to security purpose

Comment: @gauri As you can see the snippet procudes the right result, so if you're using this exact code, then your issue comes from somewhere else you didn't share. Are you *sure* your form submit handler is in the same block as `value` is defined?

Comment: @gauri its definitely a variable scope issue, you need to figure it out yourself. Check if any other variable with the same name in your current file

Answer (score 0):

Define you "value" variable outside the document.ready like below

```
var value = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
console.log(value) //Get value = false
$("#select").on('change', function(){
    value = true;
    console.log(value) //Get value = true
});

$("#form").submit(function (e) {
     console.log(value) //Get value = undefined
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this will definitely help you this is working .Please check

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
var value = false;

$("#myselect").on('change', function(){
    value = true;
   $("#myselect :selected").val(value);
});

$("#Submitbtn").on("click",function () {
    var GetSelectBoxValue= $("#myselect :selected").val();
    alert(GetSelectBoxValue);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect" >
<option value="false">one</option> 
<option value="false">two</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="Submitbtn" value="submit"/>
```